# I want to know if the channel established by the Flutter plugin is secure enough because I need to pass some sensitive information

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I want to develop a cryptocurrency wallet that relies on the Flutter plugin channel for information transmission, but I'm unsure about the reliability of Flutter channel's security.

I want to develop a cryptocurrency wallet that relies on the Flutter plugin channel for information transmission, but I'm unsure about the reliability of Flutter channel's security.1

Comment: You can use Encrypted data and pass it as string through the channel on both ends. Hope it could help.

Comment: What kind of encryption should I use to ensure its security? Can you provide some recommendations?

Comment: Additionally, will the channel between Android and Flutter be exposed and potentially monitored by other applications?

Comment: You could use AES-256 encryption and pass data as string from both sides. (flutter and native android.) This webpage will help you using it in android native [link](https://medium.com/@manuaravindpta/implementation-of-aes-encryption-in-android-dca250525b4). for flutter you can use ENCRYPT or CRYPTO plugin. But make sure to use same key at both ends.

Comment: Can't say whether the channel could be exposed or not because it solely depends on the capabilities of the hacker and flutter's mechanism behind method channel.

Comment: But my code will be open-sourced, so these encryption methods will be known by hackers. Therefore, I would like to know if there are more secure methods available to achieve communication between Android and Flutter.

Comment: What you can do in this case is sending encryption key from web service at time of login or in any other screen depending upon your flow. As far as your key is not public hackers can't access your data even if they know what encryption you are using.